# Test for at least one lowercase and uppercase character

Tags: regex, awk

How would I check a string contains at least one lowercase and at least one uppercase using `awk`.

My attempt:

```
^.*[a-z]+[A-Z]+.*$|^.*[A-Z]+[a-z]+.*$
```

Comment: Show your attempt please.

Comment: Try this link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559751/regex-to-make-sure-that-the-string-contains-at-least-one-lower-case-char-upper

Comment: I wrote a pretty in depth "Password matching" drop in regular expression for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717656/regex-no-more-than-2-identical-consecutive-characters-and-a-z-and-0-9/16717823#16717823 Maybe it will help.

Comment: my attempt: ^.*[a-z]+[A-Z]+.*$|^.*[A-Z]+[a-z]+.*$

Comment: Is there a reason that none of the other 20 questions here asking the same thing wouldn't work for you, like http://stackoverflow.com/q/1154985/62576 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/16689167/62576?

Answer (score 2):

With `awk` you can use the logical operator `&&` and test for both lowercase and uppercase using their respective character classes:

```
$ cat file
abc
ABC
aBc
123

$ awk '/[a-z]/&&/[A-Z]/{print $0,"[PASS]";next}{print $0,"[FAIL]"}' file
abc [FAIL]
ABC [FAIL]
aBc [PASS]
123 [FAIL]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. ;)

```
.*(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*
```

. = multiple times

* = any char

?= = last check should be true

[a-z]/[A-Z] = should contain the range of a-z and A-Z

You can test anytime your regex here:
[Regex Tester](http://regexpal.com/)

Comment: You don't need the opening or closing `.*` for this regex.  If you're using any anchoring methodology (like Javascript's .match), then at most you need one. (I'd select the closing one).

Comment: awk supports regex. But note that the regex implementations can be different from each tool and OS.

You can tell awk which regex you prefer. I use mostly the perl style regex.

Comment: No implementations of `awk` support look-arounds.